# Compare ZIP file with dir with shell command

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I have compressed a lot of files with zip from infozip.org.
How do I make sure that the zip file contains all the files from the original files. Or is there a GUI tool do to it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581274/diff-files-inside-of-zip-without-extracting-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a command line tool called `unzip`, and run

```
$unzip -l yourzipfile.zip
```

Files contained in `yourzipfile.zip` will be listed.

========

To verify files automatically, you can follow these steps.

If files compressed into `yourzipfile.zip` is in `dir1`, you can first unzip `yourzipfile.zip` into `dir2`, then you may compare files in `dir1` and `dir2` by running

```
$ diff --brief -r dir1/ dir2/
```

Comment: Can I maybe use diff with the dir and the output of the unzip -l to check that the content of the zip-file is the same. Because the file list is very long.

Comment: I just did find a solution with zip -t yourzipfile.zip. The -t test the yourzipfile.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this myself, and you can string together a few things to do this without unzipping to a directory

```
diff <(unzip -l foo.zip | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f4-100 | sed 's/\/$//' | sort) <(find somedir/ | sort)
```

Basic breakdown is:

Use diff to compare output streams of 2 commands

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

Use unzip -l, and process the output. I used 2 cuts to get just the filenames, remove trailing / on directories, and finally sort:

```
unzip -l foo.zip | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f4-100 | sed 's/\/$//' | sort
```

For the directory listing, a simple find and sort

```
find somedir/ | sort
```